# Is a single APEX test case considered a transaction?

Tags: apex, unit-test, transaction, mixed-dml

I'm getting DML errors when trying to test some triggers:

> This error occurred: MIXED_DML_OPERATION: DML operation on setup
>   object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or
>   vice versa).

I'm running my test case on a dev sandbox, and am inserting users before I insert a custom object.  From my understanding, this is what is causing these MIXED_DML_OPERATION errors, as I'm updating configuration and standard objects in the same transaction.

That being said, is a single APEX test considered a transaction?  Other than making changes to my code to account for testing, is there a way around inserting users in a test other than having seeAllData=true?

Comment: You can get around the mixed DML using `system.runAs()` Use SOQL to query for the Id of a single user with the System Administrator profile (you can do this without seeAllData=true). Using that User.Id you can then leverage a block of code preceded by the `system.runAs(<user.Id>)` method to insert your test Users.

Comment: don't even think about `seeAllData=true`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you do not need to set `SeeAllData=true` if you want to see `User` records in a test. **[You always see them](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm)**. Second of all, as outlined **[here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects_test_methods.htm)** the standard workaround to create a separate transaction inside your test method is to use `system.runAs(user)`.

```
system.runAs(new User(Id=UserInfo.getUserId())
{
    // separate transaction
}
```

---

In an actual test, that would look something like:

```
@IsTest
static void testSomeStuff()
{
    User admin = [
        SELECT Id FROM User
        WHERE Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'
        LIMIT 1
    ];
    // it is a good idea to query for a privileged user
    // so the test will work no matter who runs it

    system.runAs(admin)
    {
        // insert users here
        // along with any other setup data
    }

    // insert non setup objects

    Test.startTest();
        // do stuff
    Test.stopTest();

    // verify behavior using assertions
}
```